# How to make your own properties, eg. "devise :authenticable" in ruby / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

I was wondering how I could have various properties in my models. Eg:

```
Property < ActiveRecord::Base
   locatable, saleable ...
```

Would these be mixins? Or is there another way of implementing this? eg. the way devise has:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
    # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

Comment: You need to create a custom module. The :lockable [module](https://assets1.assembla.com/code/donodon/git/nodes/v0.1/vendor/gems/devise-1.0.7/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb?type=tag) is defined [here](https://assets1.assembla.com/code/donodon/git/nodes/v0.1/vendor/gems/devise-1.0.7/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb?type=tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great part about open source stuff is you can just take a look and find out.  I've removed some non-relevant lines (gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/models.rb:83):

```
def devise(*modules)

  devise_modules_hook! do
    include Devise::Models::Authenticatable
    selected_modules.each do |m|
      mod = Devise::Models.const_get(m.to_s.classify)

      if mod.const_defined?("ClassMethods")
        class_mod = mod.const_get("ClassMethods")
        extend class_mod

        if class_mod.respond_to?(:available_configs)
          available_configs = class_mod.available_configs
          available_configs.each do |config|
            next unless options.key?(config)
            send(:"#{config}=", options.delete(config))
          end
        end
      end

      include mod
    end
  end
end
```

All devise is doing (aside from housekeeping stuff) is automating looping through the splatted array of symbols you passed in, and including them (or sometimes using `extend`) into your class with `Devise::Models::#{property_name}`.

You could definitely do the same.  Whether you should or not is up to what you are doing.  Often, just seeing `include SomeModule::SomeClass` is far, far more informative than a cutsey helper method.